# Failed to perform checkout on agent: java.io.IOException: Access is denied - TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

We are getting a Access Denied error while trying to checkout on one of our teamcity Agents. The other agent is able to checkout and build fine.

I added this property  *teamcity.git.use.native.ssh=true* and checked if the teamcity user has all same permissions as the other agent and tried removing the .git file under system\git*. None of these worked.

Attaching the log file and screenshot.

[image]

Log File

````
[09:17:25] : Collecting changes in 1 VCS root
[09:17:25] :     [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] VCS Root details
[09:17:25] :         [VCS Root details] "Generic Git VCS Root" {instance id=512, parent internal id=44, parent id=GenericGitVcsRoot, description: "http://*****/tfs/SMI-RPS/RPSMain/_git/cmp#refs/heads/master"}
[09:17:26]i:     [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] Detecting changes in VCS root 'Generic Git VCS Root' (used in 'Development Insights', 'Publish Package To Octopus')
[09:17:26]i:     [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] Will collect changes for 'Generic Git VCS Root' starting from revision cfd2c37103f4c71213bf9ffd2700381ac67e038f
[09:17:26] :     [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] Compute revision for 'Generic Git VCS Root'
[09:17:26] :         [Compute revision for 'Generic Git VCS Root'] Upper limit revision: cfd2c37103f4c71213bf9ffd2700381ac67e038f
[09:17:26]i:         [Compute revision for 'Generic Git VCS Root'] MaxModId = 22287
[09:17:26] :         [Compute revision for 'Generic Git VCS Root'] Latest commit attached to build configuration (with id <= 22287): cfd2c37103f4c71213bf9ffd2700381ac67e038f
[09:17:26] :         [Compute revision for 'Generic Git VCS Root'] Computed revision: cfd2c37103f4c71213bf9ffd2700381ac67e038f
[09:17:26] : The build is removed from the queue to be prepared for the start
[09:17:26] : Starting the build on the agent "****"
[09:17:27]i: Agent time zone: America/***
[09:17:19]i: Agent is running under JRE: 1.8.0_121-b13
[09:17:19] : Updating tools for build
[09:17:19] :     [Updating tools for build] Found 1 tool used by the build: NuGet.CommandLine.3.4.4
[09:17:19] :     [Updating tools for build] All used tools are up-to-date
[09:17:19] : Clearing temporary directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[09:17:19] : Publishing internal artifacts (4s)
[09:17:24] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
[09:17:24] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[09:17:19] : Clean build enabled: removing old files from D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3b5eca5f1ef307d3
[09:17:19] : Checkout directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3b5eca5f1ef307d3
[09:17:19]E: Updating sources: auto checkout (on agent) (1m:01s)
[09:17:19] :     [Updating sources] Will use agent side checkout
[09:17:19]W:     [Updating sources] VCS Root: Generic Git VCS Root (1m:01s)
[09:17:19] :         [VCS Root: Generic Git VCS Root] revision: cfd2c37103f4c71213bf9ffd2700381ac67e038f
[09:17:19] :         [VCS Root: Generic Git VCS Root] Git version: 2.15.0.0
[09:17:19] :         [VCS Root: Generic Git VCS Root] Will use native ssh (teamcity.git.use.native.ssh=true)
[09:17:19]W:         [VCS Root: Generic Git VCS Root] Update git mirror (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-299ED72F.git) (1m:01s)
[09:17:19] :             [Update git mirror (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-299ED72F.git)] "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" config http.sslCAInfo
[09:17:19] :             [Update git mirror (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-299ED72F.git)] "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" config --unset http.sslCAInfo
[09:17:19] :             [Update git mirror (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-299ED72F.git)] "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" show-ref
[09:17:20]W:             [Update git mirror (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-299ED72F.git)] Failed to list remote repository refs, outdated local refs will not be cleaned
[09:17:20] :             [Update git mirror (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-299ED72F.git)] "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" show-ref refs/remotes/origin/master
[09:17:20] :             [Update git mirror (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-299ED72F.git)] "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" show-ref refs/heads/master
[09:18:20] :             [Update git mirror (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-299ED72F.git)] "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" init --bare
[09:18:20] :             [Update git mirror (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-299ED72F.git)] "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" config http.sslCAInfo
[09:18:20] :             [Update git mirror (D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\system\git\git-299ED72F.git)] "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" config --unset http.sslCAInfo
[09:18:20]E:     [Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
[09:18:20] : Publishing internal artifacts
[09:18:20] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
[09:18:21] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[09:18:20] : Build failed to start. Artifacts will not be published for this build
[09:18:30] : Build finished ```
````

Answer (score 1):

There could be a lot of causes of this error. A few ideas:

- Is the TeamCity agent service running as the same user on both agents?
- Are the folder permissions the same on both agents?
- Does the checkout work if you use server side checkout instead of agent side?
- Is it possible that somebody has a file / folder open on the agent causing a file lock?